# p5.js Rect() method undefined

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, game-development

I am trying to make the rectangle move with keys but it gives me this error message:

```
   function  setup(){

  createCanvas(800, 500);
  background(255, 0, 255);
}
var character = {
  size: 50,
  positionX: 400,
  positionY:  250,
  moveR: function(){
    this.positionX += size;
  },
  moveL: function(){
    this.positionX -= size;
  },
  moveUp:function(){
    this.positionY += size;

  },
  moveDown:function(){
    this.positionY -= size;
  }
};

function detectKeys(){
function keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'a'){
    character.moveL();
  }
  if(key == 'd'){
    character.moveR();
  }
  if  (key == 's'){
    character.moveDown();
  }
  if (key == 'w'){
    character.moveUp();
  }
  console.log(character.positionX, character.positionY)

}}
function draw(){
  rect(character.positionX,  character.positionY, character.size, character.size);
}
x = 1;
while(x ==  1){
  detectKeys();
  draw();
}
```

I am using p5.js.
I could use a lot of help, Any help about anything would be appreciated, I am fairly new to javascript

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this code. Why is `keyPressed` inside of `degectKeys`? A raw function declaration doesn't do anything on its own. Another thing is that you do not need to call draw yourself. P5 will do that for you. Are you following a tutorial? If so please link it.

Comment: I'm not following a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [processing](https://processing.org/) (respectively [p5.js](https://p5js.org/)) you don't need any application loop. The [`draw()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) function is continuously executed and [`keyPressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed) is called once every time a key is pressed:

```js
function  setup(){

    createCanvas(800, 500);
    background(255, 0, 255);
}

var character = {
    size: 50,
    positionX: 400,
    positionY:  250,
    moveR: function(){
      this.positionX += this.size;
    },
    moveL: function(){
      this.positionX -= this.size;
    },
    moveUp:function(){
      this.positionY += this.size;

    },
    moveDown:function(){
      this.positionY -= this.size;
    }
};

function keyPressed(){
    if(key == 'a'){
      character.moveL();
    }
    if(key == 'd'){
      character.moveR();
    }
    if  (key == 's'){
      character.moveDown();
    }
    if (key == 'w'){
      character.moveUp();
    }
    console.log(character.positionX, character.positionY)
}

function draw(){
    background(255, 0, 255);
    rect(character.positionX,  character.positionY, character.size, character.size);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

For a further documentation see [Get Started](https://p5js.org/get-started/) respectively [Global and instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).